# C: Launch command window and output to it under Windows

Tags: c, windows

I have a mutlithreaded program, written on Windows in C using MinGW.  The main thread waits for user input, while the second thread does computations and outputs data to the user.  When I start the thread, I would like to have a new window open that displays the computed data to the user (such as a command window that the c program can write output to).  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

***********EDIT***************
I have come up with the following code:
main creates a new thread, then, in the function that the thread starts in:

```
AllocConsole( );
AttachConsole( GetCurrentProcessId() );
freopen("CON", "w", stdout);
```

But, a new console does not open, and when I write to the console using WriteConsole, the output is sent to the initial console that was open.  Both AllocConsole and AttachConsole fail, with an error of ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.  I believe this means that the calling process (thread) already has a console.  Is the thread not its own "process"?

Is there a way to keep the initial console attached to the parent process and not transfer it to the child process?

Comment: +1 for using MinGW rather than VS.. You should be able to cobble something together with this reference page and a little (more) googling. MSDN - Console Functions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I don't really understand the question... isn't one console window that reads from stdin and stdout enough...? Also @enhzflep no matter how bad or good VS is, this is not a place for holywars.

Comment: @Zupoman - quite right. That's _precisely_ why I made no comparison between the two. Each have their merits. As for the question regarding the number of console windows, perhaps the program has a gui and the OP is unaware that you can either (a) set a flag in the build options that will create a program that shows the window too or (b) just change a single byte (the sub-system one) in the exe's file-header with a hex editor. :shrug:

Comment: The output will be continuously output to the screen.  At any time, the user can enter a command into the stdin at any time.  The output won't pause for the user to do this, so I want the output and the input in two separate windows.

Comment: In the edit section, you talk about threads, and then you talk about processes. Processes and threads are different things. But you could try launching a 2nd *process*, which opens the other console window, and then these two processes could communicated using some IPC mechanism, maybe a named pipe.